# Прочитать данные из стороннего приложения (SysListView32)

Tags: c#, многопоточность, uiautomation, handlers, microsoft-spy++

Добрый день
Имеется такая проблема, необходимо считать данные из другой программы **(MT5)**, в ней хранятся логи, которые выгружаются в файл, только при определенных действиях (нажимается кнопка для формирования логов или закрывается программа), в ходе исследования задачи, я рассматривал **MT5** через программу **Inspector** и **Spy++**, нашел Handler и id процесса, но при обращении через библиотеку **UI Automation** к листу, мне отображает количество логов, но с пустыми значениями. Для примера, в **МТ4** данные отображаются спокойно текстом. В итоге для себя я выделил несколько решений данной проблемы, это чтение потока процесса и от туда как то вылавливать данные, удаленный запуск функции которая формирует лог в файл или программное нажатие кнопки для формирования лога. Направьте пожалуйста на правильный путь как можно решить мою проблему?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768442/Получение-содержимого-listview-другого-окна

Comment: Test complete и аналоги

Comment: @user2455111 я так полагаю его можно использовать только как макросный элемент вызова определенной кнопки, я рассматривал этот вариант как один из костылей, но проблема только в том, что не должно быть всплывающих окон и контекстов, они могут помешать работе в основной программе

Comment: Ну это по сути баг в программе: она не предоставляет данных для UI Automation.

Comment: @VladD как я упоминал выше в MT4 можно отловить текст с помощью UI Automation, видимо в MT5 реализовали какую то защиту или еще что-то из за чего нет возможности просмотреть отображаемые данные, вот мне и интересно как еще можно попробовать вытащить их...

Comment: @Unnamed: Это на мой вкус не защита, а баг.

Comment: @VladD все возможно, может вы можете посоветовать какое ни будь решение, а то я теряюсь уже в догадках? Программное нажатие кнопки формирования лога выкидывает ошибку в C#, а работа с потоками я так полагаю ничего полезного не даст

Comment: @Unnamed: Вот это? https://www.codeproject.com/questions/238246/getting-setting-syslistview-control-items

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight на двух разных программах вываливается "Ошибка чтения памяти невозможна". Единственное что в ручную задаю процесс, так как функция не отлавливает лист внутри формы

Comment: @Unnamed там хрупкий код, который не проверяет возвращаемые значения функций и т.п. Добавьте проверку возвращаемых значений Read/WriteProcessMemory и смотрите что первым падает и какой GetLastError. "функция не отлавливает лист внутри формы" - если там несколько уровней вложенности, должно быть соответственно несколько вызовов FindWindowEx.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Получилось добраться именно до нужного Листа, но проблема теперь стоит в том, что он мне возвращает нулевые значения, может надо задавать смещения в памяти?

Comment: @Unnamed Вероятно, в новой версии ListView переделали на виртуальный режим, в котором информация не храниться внутри ListView, а вытягивается из источника данных по запросу, и сообщение LVM_GETITEMTEXT теряет смысл (поэтому и слетела UI Automation, которая скорее всего работала по тому же принципу). В виртуальном режиме ListView посылает окну-владельцу уведомление LVN_GETDISPINFO для запроса информации, и оно заполняет структуру NMLVDISPINFO (см. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774818(v=vs.85).aspx).